# JQuery background URL uncaught syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a background `slideshow` using `jQuery`. I'm trying to have a hidden `div` (`nextDiv`) on the right of `activeDiv` slide `nextDiv` over `activeDiv` so that `activeDiv` will be overlapped by `nextDiv`. Once that is done, the background of `nextDiv` will then be changed to prepare for the new background image. Below is the code I have written.

```
// Scroll background
var bgClicked = false;
var bgList = [];
$(".bg-img").each(function(idx, el) { 
    bgList.push($(el).css('background-image').substr(4, 50)); 
    bgList[idx] = bgList[idx].substr(0, bgList[idx].length -1);
    });
var bgNum = bgList.length;
var bgNextDiv = $("#bg-next");
var bgActiveDiv = $("#bg-active");
var bgActive = 0;
var bgNext = 1; 

// Scroll until clicked

console.log(bgList);

if(bgClicked == false) {

    setInterval(function() {
        $(bgList[bgNext]).animate({left:0}, 1000, 'linear', function() {
            bgActiveDiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + bgList[bgNext] + ')'); 
            bgActive = bgNext;
            bgNext = bgNext < bgNum - 1 ? bgNext + 1 : 0;
            bgNextDiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + bgList[bgNext] + ')');
        });

    }, 5000);

}
```

However, I'm getting

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://localhost:3000/img/bg2_2560x1440px.jpg`

when setting

```
bgActiveDiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + bgList[bgNext] + ')');
```

I think I missed something, but I don't know where.

Please help?

Cheers,
Agi

**EDIT 1**

Content of `bgList = ["http://localhost:3000/img/bg1_2560x1440px.jpg", "http://localhost:3000/img/bg2_2560x1440px.jpg"]`

Comment: can you provide content of $(".bg-img") , cause code
 bgActiveDiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')'); works fine for me. we need to check input data

Comment: I've added the content of `bgList` and both elements are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `bgList[bgNext]` as jQuery selector that is why you are getting error.

So, use this instead:

```
    $(".bg-img:eq(" + bgNext + ")").animate({left:0}, 1000, 'linear', function() {
        bgActiveDiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + bgList[bgNext] + ')'); 
        bgActive = bgNext;
        bgNext = bgNext < bgNum - 1 ? bgNext + 1 : 0;
        bgNextDiv.css('background-image', 'url(' + bgList[bgNext] + ')');
    });
```